# Views returns 'All taxonomy terms' in alphabetically order; can I change to Parent > child

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm outputtin taxonomy terms using Views; The field i'm calling up is 'Content: All taxonomy terms' and returning all the vocabulary 'address' .  Views then puts these into alphabetical order ie.

England, London, Victoria

I'd like it to return from Parent downwards.  Anyone know how to do this ?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like the [Hierarchical Term Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_term_formatter) module:

> This module provides hierarchical term formatters for taxonomy reference fields. In other words, it can display a taxonomy term reference on, say, a node as Parent > Child, rather than just Child.

Comment: Unfortunately installing this on my existing Drupal site causes all the fields in any views that contain taxonomy to disappear :/  Shame as this would have been perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to order them BY ID, or NAME, or WEIGHT.

You need to create in **Advance (Views)** a **Relationship** pointing to that Taxonomy Vocabulary

Then you can add a Sort Filter, in the way you want...

Comment: Hi DarkteK

I've tried with relationshiop 'Content: Taxonomy terms on node' > with my Vocabulary.   And then in sort criteria 'Taxonomy term:Weight'  . However this will attempt to order the results like this.  not the output of the 'All taxonomy terms' field .  My feeling is that it'll need to be a module that sorts this.

Comment: If you are using module: "Views PHP", just :

1. Add field 'All taxonomy terms' then "Exclude" from ur view

2. Add a "Global: PHP" field, just under the previous one

3. Edit that PHP Field with -> 'Value code' for this will be 'echo "1";'

4. Then the output code (You can check the variables avaliable for this). Once you choose your variable, for example ($row->field_areas_of_activity)just use PHP and order them with asort()

Let me know if you can follow this

Comment: Hi DarteK; Thanks for the reply.  I follow this but at the point that i have $row->term_node_tid - which would be 'England, London, Victoria'  I am unsure what PHP would be able to put that into Parent > Child order.  Or does this return data I do not know about. Many thanks.

Comment: I can't help you more from here, I really would like to help you, but I don't know how ... sorry man

Comment: No worries, thanks Darktek you've helped me enough to find an answer :) . I've managed to work out an SQL query that returns what I need. I'll post an answer when tested. Thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

The following code takes the absolute child tid and grabs all parents.  The second argument is for the amount of terms you wish to return; and the thrid for how you want to order it.

```
 /**
 * @file Orders Taxonomy
 *
 * @param $output - expecting a tid  // check this at the point of running the    function
 * @param $no_results - the number of results that you'd like to return
 * @param $order - which tid first - child or most senior parent ?
 */

 function taxonomy_order($output, $no_results = 1, $order = 'first') {

  $terms = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array($output));
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', $output);
  $all_parents = $wrapper->parents_all->value();

  ( $order == 'last' ) ? $all_parents = array_reverse($all_parents) : $all_parents;

  $stitch_term_array = '';
  foreach ($all_parents as $key => $term) {
   ($key < $no_results ) ? $stitch_term_array .= $term->name . ", " : '';
   }
  $stitch_term_array = rtrim($stitch_term_array, ', ');

  return $stitch_term_array;
```